# Navigation Drawer Icon not visible with custom action bar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to use navigation drawer with custom action bar. My action bar does not contain any menu.
I see that the Navigation Drawer icon, is not visible on the action bar when the drawer is closed. Even though I have given the drawer icon in the `ActionbarToggle` implementation. The drawer icon appears when the `navigation drawer` is open, but disappears when the `navigation drawer` closes.

**Activty**

```
 public void setCustomActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
}
```

**NavigationDrawer Fragment**

```
getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
) {...
```

As you can see I have provided the drawer icon above. 
Why is this happening and what is the solution to this?

Comment: you need to set icon using getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.);

Comment: @MeenalSharma : Nope, it doesn't work:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are creating your own custom layout.Suppose I have this xml layout given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="#cccccc">
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_toggle"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can do this:

```
Button toggle = (Button) yourDrawerView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_toggle);   
toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isDrawerOpen = yourDrawerLayoutRefference.isDrawerOpen(yourDrawerLayout);
                if(isDrawerOpen){
                         toggle.closeDrawer(yourDrawerLayout);
                       }
                else{
                       toggle.openDrawer(yourDrawerLayout);
                    }


            }
        });
```

Comment: "then provide a button on top right corner and toggle drawer open and close on it." - I didn't get this part.